# error while install a package

Tags: debian, apt

I have a problem when I want to install `python-pycurl` package:

```
root@edx:/var/tmp/configuration-master/playbooks# apt-get install python-pycurl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-pycurl
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 179 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/62.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 233 kB of additional disk space will be used.
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pycurl_7.19.3.1-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 parse error, in file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 7 package 'python-pycurl':
 `Depends' field, invalid package name `python:any': character `:' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters `-+._')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-pycurl_7.19.3.1-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know where the problem is, here is my `/etc/apt/source.list` file :

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main non-free

#mirrors
deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free  

# Base repository
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free

# Stable updates
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
```

Does someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the package is broken. You have unstable repository enables. It is called "Unstable" for a reason.

Comment: what must I do now ?